# Cannot see dumped stats on scrapy

Tags: amazon-s3, statistics, scrapy

When I run the examples provided in the scrapy tutorial, I can see the logs printed in the stdout:

```
2014-07-10 16:08:21+0100 [pubs] INFO: Spider opened
2014-07-10 16:08:21+0100 [pubs] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 
2014-07-10 16:08:21+0100 [pubs] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-07-10 16:08:21+0100 [pubs] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 471,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 3897,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 15, 8, 21, 970741),
'item_scraped_count': 1,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 15, 8, 21, 584373)}
2014-07-10 16:08:21+0100 [pubs] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

However, when I change the setting 'FEED_URI' to export the result file into S3, I do not see the stats anywhere. I have tried printing crawler.stats.spider_stats but it's still empty. Any ideas?

Comment: see the various `LOG_` settings: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-LOG_FILE

Answer (score 1):

I could not get scrapy to dump the stats, even with 'LOG_ENABLED' and 'DUMP_STATS' set to true. However, I found a workaround by dumping the stats manually by adding this line of code at the end of my reactor simulation:

```
log.msg("Dumping Scrapy stats:\n" + pprint.pformat(crawler.stats.get_stats()))
```